# Logarithmic derivative of matrix function

Tags: logarithms, matrix-calculus, matrix-norms, matrix-analysis

in my research I ended up with a term of the following form:
$$ C(x)^\prime:C^{-1}(x)^\prime $$
In my case the matrix function $C(x)\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ and is always s.p.d. so we can rewrite the above as
$$ -\text{trace}(C^{-\frac{1}{2}}C^\prime C^{-\frac{1}{2}}C^{-\frac{1}{2}}C^\prime C^{-\frac{1}{2}})  = \|C^{-\frac{1}{2}}C^\prime C^{-\frac{1}{2}} \|_F^2. $$

Actually I want to know if $C^{-\frac{1}{2}}C^\prime C^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ can be written as derivative of a matrix function, i.e. $F(C)^\prime$.

I know that if $C$ and $C^\prime$ commutes then $F=\log(C)$.

However, in the non-commuting case the derivative of the matrix logarithmn is quite ugly. However I saw something on logarithmic derivatives which share some properties, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/723325/774429).

Maybe somebody has an idea or a reference for this  logarithmic derivatives.

Comment: What is the first equation supposed to mean? (What is ":"?) In any case the first equation seems a matrix equation while the second is a scalar.

Comment: The ":" is the frobenius inner product so C:D = tr(CD^T)=tr(C^TD).

Comment: No offense but that's not the most fortunate notation. The answer to your question is the derivative of the primitive. But what does the question has to do with the context?

Comment: If your matrix were diagonal or orthogonal, then the expression for the logarithm (and its gradient) would be greatly simplified.  Unfortunately, the fact that a matrix is symmetric or hermitian or SPD does not help and you're stuck with an unwieldy expansion like Magnus or Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff.